# Tableau Average of "above average values"

Tags: average, aggregation, tableau-api, median

Supposing I have many plots on a y-x axes. I want to calculate the average of all the curves/points above the `“average curve”`  and the average of all the curves below the `“average curve”.`

I have created a measure that is the “average curve” using the following calculation:

```
AverageLF  = AVG([LF])
```

I am trying to create  a measure that would express the average of all the points above average using something some sort of conditional averaging like this:

```
AboveAverage  = AVG (  IF [LF]>[AverageLF] THEN [LF] END   )
```

Apparently I get the: "Cannot mix aggregate and non-aggregate arguments" calculation error.
I want to do the same with the median. (median of all the points above, median of all the points below the median)
I am relative new to `TABLEAU` and this is very important for my work, could you please advise?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Correct me if I am wrong,
you want to check if the values in `[LF]` are `> [AverageLF]` if yes then take them aside and do an average of those values. is that correct?
If yes then do this,

```
AboveAverage  =  IF [LF]>[AverageLF] THEN [LF] END
```

Now you have a value `AboveAverage` which has list of all values `> [AverageLF]`
Now Create a calculated field,

```
 Final = Avg(AboveAverage)
```

This should have average of all values `AboveAverage`.

Let me know if this works.

Comment: Thanks for your answer Ajinkya! I've already tried to do it but I get "Cannot mix aggregate and non-aggregate arguments in IF expressions" error since [AverageLF] is aggregate and [LF] is non-aggregate.

Comment: This is exactly what LOD calculations are for. Read the help and blogs about them and you should be able to answer your own question.